# Prefill Google form from user first & last name on google account

Tags: google-forms

I would like to make a pre-filled link for a google form that will prefill a field with the last name of their gmail account.  That way I can send the same link to many gmail address within the company and when they fill out the form their last name is pre-filled.

This is the url I have right now.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfXWo_RFxv10luU28-zY7R8VLAFkxq_w-xwd1-5_89a0F9dsA/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.311678919&entry.1133288578=Add%20Fare&entry.1921770549&entry.1777391530&entry.198140008&entry.2092957064&entry.464790042=Gas&entry.1410965432&entry.1717787027

Edited for clarity.

Comment: We have no idea what that URL is part of.  Are you using Apps Script?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: This is the link that google provided me when I selected which fields I wanted prefilled.  I would like to use App Script to do this task.

Comment: You will need to learn some JavaScript and some Apps Script basics to be able to do this.  We can't provide an answer that will somehow put the knowledge of JavaScript and Apps Script into your brain.  You need to do the work to learn it yourself.  Here is some basic information:  [Link to Apps Script - Getting Started](https://sites.google.com/view/apps-script-getting-started/home)

Comment: I intend to learn JS basics soon. Taught myself VBA so it's doable.